# Find Missing Relationships using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables, a `Users` table, a `Preferences` table, and a `User_Preferences` table. They look like this:

`Users` Table:

- **User_ID**: Primary Key
- **User_Name**: Username
- ... other unimportant fields

`Preferences` Table:

- **Pref_ID**: Primary Key
- **Pref_Name**: Preference Name
- ... other unimportant fields

`User_Preferences` Table:

- **Pref_ID**: The User the Preference is for
- **User_ID**: The Preference being set
- **Pref_Val**: The Value of the Preference

Over the years, many new Preferences have been added, but now the underlying architecture has change somewhat. Before, if the `User_Preferences` table didn't contain a link for a certain `Preference`, no matter, but now, every `Preference` needs to be assigned to every `User`.

So, given those three tables are populated, what query can I run that will give me a list of `User_Preferences` that are missing?

For example, if there are 2 users, and 2 permissions, and the first user has both but the second has one, it will give me a single row for that user and that permission

Comment: What have you done so far? Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `cross join` to generate all combinations and then filter out the ones that exist using a `left join`:

```
select u.*, p.*
from users u cross join
     preferences p left join
     user_preferences up
     on up.user_id = u.user_id and up.preference_id = p.preference_id
where up.user_id is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative with an EXISTS.

```
SELECT p.preference_id,
    u.user_id
FROM users u
CROSS JOIN preferences p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT NULL
    FROM user_preferences up
    WHERE up.user_id = u.user_id
    AND up.preference_id = p.preference_id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.User_ID, p.Pref_ID from users u, preferences p
minus
select User_ID, Pref_ID from user_preferences
```

Comment: Could you explain why your answer is the solution to the problem?