# Find tables relationships only by examining the tables content using SQL scripts

Tags: sql

Given two tables that display no relation between them.
Can you determine the probability for two columns to be in an undeclared relationship?

Just to make me understood: You can take any related tables. You delete the reference between them. Can you guess the original relation only by examining their content with procedural language or a series of SQL scripts (suppose you have enough data you need) ?

Related to missing relationship there is another question: [Find Missing Relationships using PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267927/find-missing-relationships-using-pl-sql). Here the user already knows the columns that participate in the missing relationship. In my case, I want to detect which are those columns.

You can exemplify for any database type you are used with (SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, etc...)

Comment: Can't you just use column names to make a guess?

Comment: It is a good practice to follow a naming conversion that can suggest the relations. Sometimes, and for projects really old, the naming convention is inconsistent.

Comment: Also, there are column names that suggest a relation but the content does not follow the suggestion.

Comment: *"You can exemplify for any database type you are used with (SqlServer, Oracle, MySql, etc...)"* - no you can not. PL/SQL is not available in _any database_. Are you looking for PL/SQL (that is Oracle only) or general database agnostic solution ?

Comment: You are right. Even if other databases implement something similar to PL/SQL, the name is specific to Oracle. PostgreSQL name his  SQL Procedural Language as PL/pgSQL, for example. Or T-SQL for SqlServer. But once an algorithm exists for one database, I can use it as a model to develop my own scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I created such an attempt. A lot can be improved.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  value int := 0;

  schema_name_1 text;
  table_name_1 text;
  column_name_1 text;
  sql_1 text;
  res_1 record;

  schema_name_2 text;
  table_name_2 text;
  column_name_2 text;
  sql_2 text;
  res_2 record;

BEGIN
  schema_name_1='public';
  table_name_1='Table1';
  column_name_1='"Id"';

  schema_name_2='public';
  table_name_2='Table2';
  column_name_2='"Id"';

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _x;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _x (
    "Info" text,
    "C1" text,
    "C2" text,
    "Sql1" text,
    "Sql2" text
  );

   sql_1 := concat('ALTER TABLE _x RENAME COLUMN "C1" TO "', schema_name_1, '.', table_name_1, '";');
   sql_2 := concat('ALTER TABLE _x RENAME COLUMN "C2" TO "', schema_name_2, '.', table_name_2, '";');
   EXECUTE sql_1;
   EXECUTE sql_2;

   BEGIN
       -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       sql_1 := concat('SELECT count(t1.', column_name_1, ') AS count FROM ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1;');
       sql_2 := concat('SELECT count(t2.', column_name_2, ') AS count FROM ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2;');

       res_1 = null;
       res_2 = null;

       FOR res_1 IN EXECUTE sql_1 LOOP
            INSERT INTO _x VALUES (
            'Count',
            res_1.count,
            0,
            sql_1,
            sql_2
        );
        END LOOP;
        FOR res_2 IN EXECUTE sql_2 LOOP
            sql_2 := concat('UPDATE _x SET "', schema_name_2, '.', table_name_2, '" = ', res_2.count, ' WHERE "Info" = ''Count'';');
            EXECUTE sql_2;   
        END LOOP;
        RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', res_1.count, res_2.count, sql_1;            
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        sql_1 = concat('SELECT count(DISTINCT(t1.', column_name_1, ')) AS count FROM ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1;');
        sql_2 = concat('SELECT count(DISTINCT(t2.', column_name_2, ')) AS count FROM ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2;');

    res_1 = null;
    res_2 = null;

        FOR res_1 IN EXECUTE sql_1 LOOP
            INSERT INTO _x VALUES (
            'Distinct Count',
            res_1.count,
            0,
            sql_1,
            sql_2
        );
        END LOOP;
        FOR res_2 IN EXECUTE sql_2 LOOP
            sql_2 := concat('UPDATE _x SET "', schema_name_2, '.', table_name_2, '" = ', res_2.count, ' WHERE "Info" = ''Distinct Count'';');
            EXECUTE sql_2;   
        END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', res_1.count, res_2.count, sql_1;            
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        sql_1 = concat('SELECT count(t1.', column_name_1, ') AS count FROM ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1 JOIN ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2 ON t1.', column_name_1, '= t2.', column_name_2, ';');
        sql_2 = concat('SELECT count(t2.', column_name_2, ') AS count FROM ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2 JOIN ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1 ON t1.', column_name_1, '= t2.', column_name_2, ';');

    res_1 = null;
    res_2 = null;

        FOR res_1 IN EXECUTE sql_1 LOOP
            INSERT INTO _x VALUES (
            'Matched',
            res_1.count,
            0,
            sql_1,
            sql_2
        );
        END LOOP;
        FOR res_2 IN EXECUTE sql_2 LOOP            
            sql_2 := concat('UPDATE _x SET "', schema_name_2, '.', table_name_2, '" = ', res_2.count, ' WHERE "Info" = ''Matched'';');
            EXECUTE sql_2;   
        END LOOP;
        RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', res_1.count, res_2.count, sql_1;
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        sql_1 = concat('SELECT count(t1.', column_name_1, ') AS count FROM ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1 LEFT JOIN ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2 ON t1.', column_name_1, '= t2.', column_name_2, ' WHERE t2.', column_name_2, ' IS NULL;');
        sql_2 = concat('SELECT count(t2.', column_name_2, ') AS count FROM ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2 LEFT JOIN ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1 ON t1.', column_name_1, '= t2.', column_name_2, ' WHERE t1.', column_name_1, ' IS NULL;');

    res_1 = null;
    res_2 = null;

        FOR res_1 IN EXECUTE sql_1 LOOP
            INSERT INTO _x VALUES (
            'Unlinked',
            res_1.count,
            0,
            sql_1,
            sql_2
        );
        END LOOP;
        FOR res_2 IN EXECUTE sql_2 LOOP            
            sql_2 := concat('UPDATE _x SET "', schema_name_2, '.', table_name_2, '" = ', res_2.count, ' WHERE "Info" = ''Unlinked'';');
            EXECUTE sql_2;   
        END LOOP;
        RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', res_1.count, res_2.count, sql_1;
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        sql_1 = concat('SELECT MAX(t.count0) AS count FROM (SELECT count(*) AS count0 FROM ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1 JOIN ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2 ON t1.', column_name_1, '= t2.', column_name_2, ' GROUP BY t2.', column_name_2, ') AS t;');
        sql_2 = concat('SELECT MAX(t.count0) AS count FROM (SELECT count(*) AS count0 FROM ', schema_name_2, '."', table_name_2, '" AS t2 JOIN ', schema_name_1, '."', table_name_1, '" AS t1 ON t1.', column_name_1, '= t2.', column_name_2, ' GROUP BY t1.', column_name_1, ') as t;');

    res_1 = null;
    res_2 = null;

        FOR res_1 IN EXECUTE sql_1 LOOP
            INSERT INTO _x VALUES (
            'Multiplicity',
            res_1.count,
            0,
            sql_1,
            sql_2
        );
        END LOOP;
        FOR res_2 IN EXECUTE sql_2 LOOP
            sql_2 := concat('UPDATE _x SET "', schema_name_2, '.', table_name_2, '" = ', res_2.count, ' WHERE "Info" = ''Multiplicity'';');
            EXECUTE sql_2;   
        END LOOP;
        RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %', res_1.count, res_2.count, sql_1;
        -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    END;
END; $$;

SELECT * FROM _x;
```

Output:

```
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Info             | Table1.Id | Table2.Id |  SQL1                                                                        |
|-----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|"Count"          |"7386359"  |"12264"    | "SELECT count(t1."Id") AS count FROM public."Table1" AS t1                   |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|"Distinct Count" |"7386359"  |"12264"    | "SELECT count(DISTINCT(t1."Id")) AS count FROM public."Table1" AS t1         |
|-----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|"Matched"        |"12264"    |"12264"    | "SELECT count(t1."Id") AS count FROM public."Table1" AS t1                   |
|                 |           |           |     JOIN public."Table2" AS t2 ON t1."Id"= t2."Id"                           |
|-----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|"Unlinked"       |"7374095"  |"0"        | "SELECT count(t1."Id") AS count FROM public."Table1" AS t1                   |
|                 |           |           |     LEFT JOIN public."Table2" AS t2 ON t1."Id"= t2."Id" WHERE t2."Id" IS NULL|
|-----------------+-----------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|"Multiplicity"   |"1"        |"1"        | "SELECT MAX(t.count0) AS count FROM (SELECT count(*) AS count0               |
|                 |           |           |     FROM public."Table1" AS t1 JOIN public."Table1" AS t2 ON t1."Id"= t2."Id"|
|                 |           |           |     GROUP BY t2."Id") AS t                                                   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```